# How to get correct datetime format in dateTimePicker after double click on datagridview row without parsing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am working on windows form application.

It contains two form MainForm - Test and childForm - Search. Search form has dataGridView control.
And Main form contain dateTimePicker1 control.
[image]

My Question is - When I double click on row from datagridview, my dateTimePicker shows the date in dd/MM/yyyy format as shown in above. But it shows in MM/dd/yyyy format.

DateTimePicker control properties

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.dateTimePicker1.Name = "dateTimePicker1";
this.dateTimePicker1.Value = new System.DateTime(2018, 6, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Main Form Code :

```
private void SearchTestToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var searchForm = new SearchTest())
    {
        DataRow currentRow = null;

        if (searchForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (searchForm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
                currentRow = ((DataRowView)searchForm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Row;

            if (currentRow != null)
            {
                tb_SerialNo.Text = (string)currentRow["SrNo"];
                tb_TypeNo.Text = (string)currentRow["TypeNo"];
                tb_TestEngineer.Text = (string)currentRow["TestEngineer"];
                dateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime)currentRow["Date"]; // here I am getting date from gridview in dd/MM/yyyy format 
            }   
        }    
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";  
   }
}  

private void ReadFile()
{
    dt = new DataTable("Model1");
    dt.Columns.Add("SrNo", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TypeNo", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TestEngineer", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.ReadXml(filePath);
}
```

SearchTest Form Code:

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

My XML data:

```
<SrNo>AB_1</SrNo>
<TypeNo>CSE104</TypeNo>
<TestEngineer>JR</TestEngineer>
<Date>2018-02-07T00:00:00+05:30</Date>
```

I don't want to use ParseExact method.

Comment: The date that you have in the XMl file is 7th of February. All other things seem working well.

Comment: To not get confused about day and month, test your code with a date like `25/12/2018`.

Comment: Its in yyyy-dd-MM format. Its today's date.

Comment: Actually problem is in this line of code -  dateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime)currentRow["Date"]; ..(DateTime)currentRow["Date"] this gives me dd/MM/yyyy format and dateTimePicker1.Value its in MM/dd/yyyy format

Comment: Try this: `var m = DateTime.Parse("2018-02-07T00:00:00+05:30").Month; MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());`  and see the month.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Its month. Means I am doing mistake in writing XML..Means in creating row.